# Iterating through a list of objects that belong to an object

Tags: python

I am trying to build my own network of nodes and analyse it. I have a `Node` class and a `Network` class:

```
class Node():

    def __init__(self, ID, team):
        self.ID = ID
        self.team = team
        self.edge = (None, None)


class Network():

    def __init__(self, number_of_green_nodes):
        self.green_network = [Node(ID = i, team = "Green") for i in range(number_of_green_nodes)]
```

I then create a network object, `network1`, consisting of 10 `Node` objects:

```
network1 = network.Network(10)
```

I now want to iterate through the network's list of nodes, and access some attributes of the `Node` objects. For instance, to access the `ID` attribute of each of the nodes, I do the following:

```
for i in network1.green_network:
    print(network1.green_network[i].ID)
```

But this results in the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Node
```

So how is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`network1.green_network` is a list and with the for cycle you're directly iterating through that list:

```
for node in network.green_network:
    print(node.ID)
```

Or, if you need the index, that is useless since it is the same as the ID for how you initialize the network:

```
for i, node in enumerate(network.green_network):
    print(f'Node in position {i} has ID {node.ID}')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(network1.green_network)):
    print(network1.green_network[i].ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used the for-each notation; so the `i` is a `Node` not an integer.

```py
for node in network1.green_network:
    print(node.ID)
```

If you want to mutate them:

```py
for i in range(10):
    print(network1.green_network[i].ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `i` iterates through the list of nodes. Thus, the values it takes are of type `Network`, since this is what the `network1.green_network` list contains.

The error happens because you try to index a list using data of type `Network` as an index, which is not possible, it needs to be of type `int`.

In order to access both the `Network` objects and their index, you can try:

```
for node, index in zip(network1.green_network, range(len(network1.green_network))):
    print(node.ID)
    print(network1.green_network[index].ID)
```